# How to get insert statement with data as String

Tags: sql, scala, sql-insert, slick, slick-3.0

Perhaps I use `Table.insertStatementFor` wrong.

I'm using Slick 3.0.x and Scala-2.11.x

There are the following classes and objects:

```
case class User(id:Int, name:String)

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = (id, name) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}

val table = TableQuery[Users]
```

I want to get insert statement string with data. 
The method `table.insertStatement` returns

```
INSERT INTO users(id, name) VALUES(?,?)
```

I want to get the following string for `User(1, "John")`:

```
INSERT INTO users(id, name) VALUES(1, 'John');
```

I tried use method `table.insertStatementFor(User(1, "John"))`, but it is not works and raised exception:

```
not enough arguments for method insertStatementFor: (implicit shape: scala.slick.lifted.Shape[_ <: scala.slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel, models.User, ...
```

Does the solution of this task exist?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? In slick you can just do something like ```table += (1, "John")``` to insert a new value.

Comment: I want to create some sql-dataset for executing in tests which use sql-fixtures. Another use case is about generating sql-patches.
Anyway it seems to me that I've found a `insertStatementFor` method to solve my task. But perhaps I use it wrong.